# Need to install a existing project on symfony 1.4 using command line

Tags: symfony-1.4

I Have an existing project on symfony 1.4 and need to install it using command line so that it works properly.

Comment: What do you mean `install`? Do you mean update?

Comment: Actualli i want to update only but for now i want to setup the project on my localhost which is in symfony 1.4

Comment: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Doctrine describes the process pretty well